# var key word and using name space

Tags: c#, namespaces, var

I have a method `ExecuteQuery` and it is returning a `Datatable` object which is a method of object `_dataAccess`, this will compile proper with out using `System.Data`

```
string query = "select * from UserNeeds where userNeedID =" + item.ParentId;
var result = _dataAccess.ExecuteQuery(query, CommandType.Select);
foreach (var rows in result.Rows)
{

}
```

but if i changed var and if give orginal type `Datatable` it will show comiple time error as we missed `System.Data`.

My question is how compiler can understand that `System.Data` is the name space when we keep `var` as type.

or why it is forcing when we use orginal `datatype` in place of `var`, how compiler handing the same ?

Comment: basicaly var is an anonymous type you can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Comment: @m.rogalski: [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is not an anonymous type, it's not even related to it. The keword `var` is just like a placeholder for the actual type of that variable. So you don't need to write `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>();` but you can use `var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` is not a type by itself, it's a placeholder for the actual type which will be resolved by the compiler. Since [`DataRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135386(v=vs.110).aspx)(returned by `DataRable.Rows`) does not implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>` but only the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface the `foreach` object `rows` is of type `Object`. So you can't use `DataRow` properties and methods in the loop.

You need to cast it everytime or let it be casted by the `foreach`:

```
foreach (DataRow row in result.Rows)
{

}
```

Now you need to add  `using System.Data` to the top of your file or use

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in result.Rows)
{

}
```

So the reason why it compiles with `var` without adding the namespace is that the compiler uses `System.Object` for the `var` because `DataRowCollection` yields objects not DataRows.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace is a short  notation of any object. If you dont specify then you need to give the full object name.

Var is a one time dynamic data type which stores the object types once it creates dynamically with full object name.